# GitHub actions error: Unrecognized named-value: 'github'

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to build a docker gh actions workflow that can be reusable and takes some parameters such as the registry and image name.

I have published the code as an open source repo [here](https://github.com/VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action).

Here is the current version of the code in case it changes in the future:

```
name: VewDockerAction
description: Easily builds and publishes Docker images. See readme.md at VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action
on:
   workflow_dispatch:
     inputs:
      context:
        description: The context used for the "docker build" command.
        required: true
      dockerfile:
        description: The dockerfile used for the "docker build" command.
        required: true
      image_name:
        description: The name of the image to publish
        required: true
      registry:
        description: The registry where the image will be uploaded.
        required: true
      registry-user:
        description: The username used for the login.
        required: true
      registry-password:
        description: The password used for the login to the registry.
        required: true 
jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build Docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      if: github.event_name != 'release'
      with:
        context: ${{ github.events.inputs.context }}
        file: ${{ github.events.inputs.dockerfile }}
        push: false
        tags: ${{ github.events.inputs.image_name }}:${{ github.sha }}
    - name: Login to Registry
      if: github.event_name == 'release'
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        registry: ${{ github.events.inputs.registry }}
        username: ${{ github.events.inputs.registry-user }}
        password: ${{ github.events.inputs.registry-password }}
    - name: Build and Push Docker image
      if: github.event_name == 'release'
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: ${{ github.events.inputs.context }}
        file: ${{ github.events.inputs.dockerfile }}
        push: true
        tags: |
          ${{ github.events.inputs.registry }}/${{ github.events.inputs.image_name }}:${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
          ${{ github.events.inputs.registry }}/${{ github.events.inputs.image_name }}:latest
```

I have published it to the marketplace and I am calling the actions workflow like this:

```
- name: VewDockerAction
      # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
      # uses: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action@c58569dca571435a7422a0d55dde082d6bacef22
      uses: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action@v1.1.3
      with:
        # The context used for the "docker build" command.
        context: . 
        # The dockerfile used for the "docker build" command.
        dockerfile: Web/Dockerfile
        # The name of the image to publish
        image_name: charwiki/web
        # The registry where the image will be uploaded.
        registry: ghcr.io 
        # The username used for the login.
        registry-user: ${{ github.actor }}
        # The password used for the login to the registry.
        registry-password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 36, Col: 18):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 37, Col: 15):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 39, Col: 15):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 44, Col: 19):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 45, Col: 19):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 46, Col: 19):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 51, Col: 18):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 52, Col: 15):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 54, Col: 15):
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 36, Col: 18): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.context
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 37, Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.dockerfile
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 39, Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.image_name
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 44, Col: 19): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.registry
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 45, Col: 19): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.registry-user
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 46, Col: 19): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.registry-password
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 51, Col: 18): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.context
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 52, Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.dockerfile
Error: VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml (Line: 54, Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.events.inputs.registry
Error: Fail to load VewTech/Vew-Docker-Action/v1.1.3/action.yml
```

I have tried adding the "on workflow call/on workflow dispatch" events to the flow, as well as changing "inputs.var" to "github.events.inputs.var" as suggested [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1035). However, I am still getting the error.

How can I pass variables to my workflow using with?

Comment: That looks more like a GHA workflow and not an action if `description` is removed and `events` is changed to `event`.

Comment: See [About custom actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions). Most probably, you wanted to create a [custom composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action).